# SQL check constraint on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

So If the "Type" is 0, i should be able to add my person in Table B, else not, but the "Type" column is not and shouldn't be in Table B.
[image]

Comment: `Instead of` trigger might be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a foreign key constraint and some trickery.

First, set up a unique constraint on `TableA` for both `type` and `person`:

```
alter table TableA add constraint unq_TableA_type_person on TableA(type, person);
```

This allows you set to set up a foreign key constraint.  However, you need a `type` column.  For that, you can use a computed column:

```
alter table TableB add type_for_a as (0);   -- it is always 0
```

Now, just use a foreign key constraint:

```
alter table TableB add constraint fk_tableA_type_person
    foreign key (type_for_a, person) references tableA(type, person);
```

Voila!  You have the constraint in place without having to write any code.

Comment: I got a little confused... So basically on ` alter table TableB add constraint fk_tableA_type_person
    foreign key (type_for_a, person) references tableA(type, person); ` part of the code I am making a foreign key with two columns??

Comment: isn't there something simpler idk... `pseudo code` IF TABLE A CELL X =0 LET IT PASS IN, OTHERWISE DON'T`

Comment: i think i forgot to mention that the "Type" doesn't exist in the other table

Comment: now i see i didn't clarify the question enough... I edited it can u check it again?

Comment: @bethe . . . So?  This doesn't really add a `type` column to the table.   It adds a computed column that is never stored.  You can called it `_type` or something else if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (TypeID INT NOT NULL, people VARCHAR(50));
GO
CREATE TABLE T2 ( people VARCHAR(50));
GO


-- creating trigger to insert on the behalf when there is a particular type
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.AfterInsertTrigger 
   ON  T1
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @id int,
     @someval char(1)
    insert into dbo.T2
    select i.people   FROM Inserted i
    where i.TypeID=0 -- checks only when the id is 0
END
GO

-- inserting people with different id s into Table1
INSERT T1 (TypeID, people) SELECT 1, 'A';
INSERT T1 (TypeID, people) SELECT 0, 'B';
GO

--selecting from tables see what got affected.
select * from T1
select *from T2
```

[image]

```
 --Clean up
    DROP TABLE T2;
    DROP TABLE T1;
    GO
```

Comment: a little explaination would be helpful :)

Comment: @bethe, please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: in my case the FKID mustn't exist in the T2

Comment: now i see i didn't clarify the question enough... I edited it can u check it again?

Comment: so if you just want to add a value based on 0 you can use tirggers

Comment: what kind of trigger... I'm thinking to change my database structure lol

Comment: @bethe please see if this explains